# Can we check whether an element(link, image, header etc) is displayed on the page using Nokogiri?

Tags: selenium, nokogiri

Is that possible to check with Nokogiri that the element is visible on the page while creating Automation script using Selenium?

Example:
With Ruby we can check as: `@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//path").displayed? == true`
any thing using Nokogiri?

Comment: No, we can't. JavaScript can change that attribute without the HTML being affected. Nokogiri only knows about the HTML, and doesn't interpret JavaScript, or have visibility into the DOM used by the browser.

Comment: hi.. is there any alternative way you are aware of that i can use to check?

Comment: You *might* be able to use Watir driving a browser to find out.